# Compartir Variables En Java

Tags: java

¿Cómo Puedo hacer que mi variable valor3 se compartan en los 2 private void? me refiero a que compartan el mismo valor siempre. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void empezarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int valor1 = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);
    int valor2 = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);
    numero1.setText(""+valor1);
    numero2.setText(""+valor2);
    int valor3 = valor1+valor2;
}                                       

private void verificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int resultado1=Integer.parseInt(resultado.getText());
    if (resultado1 == valor3 ){}
}
```

Comment: Puedes declarar ambas variables como miembros de la clase, en el cuerpo de la misma (fuera de todos los métodos)

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente crea una variable de clase (variable miembro) y esta sera leida por ambos mètodos:

```
private int valor3;

private void empezarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int valor1 = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);
    int valor2 = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);
    numero1.setText(""+valor1);
    numero2.setText(""+valor2);
    //int valor3 = valor1+valor2;
    valor3 = valor1+valor2;
}                                       

private void verificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int resultado1=Integer.parseInt(resultado.getText());
    if (resultado1 == valor3 ){}
}
```

Te sugiero revisar:

[Variables miembro (Ámbito a nivel de clase) y Variables locales](https://javadesdecero.es/basico/ambito-variables-scope/)

---

> **1. Variables miembro (Ámbito a nivel de clase)** Estas variables deben declararse dentro de la clase (fuera de cualquier método). Se puede
> acceder directamente a ellas en cualquier parte de la clase. Echemos
> un vistazo a un ejemplo:

```
public class Test {
     //Todas las variables definidas directamente dentro de una clase
     //son variables miembro
     int a;
     private String b;
     void method1() {....}
     int method2() {....}
     char c; 
}
```

> Podemos declarar variables de clase en cualquier lugar de la clase, pero fuera de los métodos. El acceso especificado de las
> variables miembro no afecta el alcance de ellas dentro de una clase.
> Se puede acceder a las variables miembro fuera de una clase con las
> siguientes reglas

> **2. Variables locales (Ámbito a nivel de método)** Las variables declaradas dentro de un método tienen alcance a nivel de método y no
> se puede acceder fuera del método.

```
public class Test
{
    void method1() 
    {
       // Variable local (ámbito a nivel de método)
       int x;
    }
}
```

> × Nota: Las variables locales no existen después de que finaliza la
> ejecución del método.

Answer (score 2):

La variable `valor3` tiene que ser atributo de la clase donde se encuentran los 2 métodos

```
public class Prueba{
  private int valor3;

  private void empezarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int valor1 = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);
    int valor2 = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);
    numero1.setText(""+valor1);
    numero2.setText(""+valor2);
    valor3 = valor1+valor2;

  }                                       

  private void verificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int resultado1=Integer.parseInt(resultado.getText());
    if (resultado1 == valor3 ){}
  } 

}
```